# Loading spinner using angular 7 http interceptor is not working on page reload

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have written HTTP interceptor to show the loader spinner for each REST call.
This service works fine on all other instances than page reload.
The loader spinner is loaded for all Rest calls if we navigate programmatically or do some action on the screen.

But it does not work at the time of page load or reload.

Can someone please suggest solution.

Comment: Angular doesn't always resend requests. It's better to put code into start route guards.

Comment: interceptor loader will only work if service gets called. and service get called after the page is loaded until then you need check router events for the loader to work

Answer (score 0):

Inside `index.html` reuse the HTML and CSS of your loader screen. Put the styles in the `<style></style>` tag and the HTML *inside* your root component.

```
<style>CSS goes here</style>

<app-root>HTML goes here</app-root>
```